# 'sleepymongoose' is not defined?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to set up sleepy.mongoose, a mongoDB REST interface using the [instructions here.](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/)

I am using windows 8, :( ...anyway... I have python 3.3.2 installed and it is accessible from the cmd prompt. I also have pymongo installed, when i enter `help('modules')` to python, pymongo is on the list of available modules!

But when I try to run `python httpd.py` from the sleepy.mongoose dir (thanks karthikr), I get an error:

```
C:\Users\Brook\Desktop\sleepy.mongoose>python httpd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "httpd.py", line 1, in <module>
    sleepymongoose/httpd.py
NameError: name 'sleepymongoose' is not defined
```

Now I tried actually `cd`ing into the proper dir, but I get this other error:

```
C:\Users\Brook\Desktop\sleepy.mongoose\sleepymongoose>python httpd.py
  File "httpd.py", line 221
    print "\n================================="
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: cd into `sleepymongoose/` and then `python httpd.py`

Comment: well, that seems obvious, my bad, but i still get an error, updated question...

Comment: You are using python3.x and sleepymongoose does not support 3.x yet

Comment: mmm, ill try 2, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using python 3 to run python 2 code. The syntax for `print` amongst other things has changed. Use Python 2 or a server which supports python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with Python 2.7 on Windows. Considering 'httpd.py' wich contains only:

```
sleepymongoose/httpd.py
```

You need this command line to start it:

```
python sleepymongoose/httpd.py
```